# AWS CDK - API Gateway LambdaIntegration - passing a literal using requestParameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to pass a literal value to the called lambda function using API gateway integration `requestParameters` but with no luck.

My current code is:

```js
myApigatewayResource.addMethod(
    'GET',
    new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(
        myLambdaFunctionHandler,
        {
            requestParameters: {
                'integration.request.querystring.customvalue': '123456789'
            }
        }
    ),
    {
        methodResponses: [
            { statusCode: '200' },
        ]
    }
);
```

When running `cdk synth && cdk deploy` I get the error:

```
Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: 123456789
```

Official documentation for [LambdaIntegrationOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.LambdaIntegrationOptions.html#requestparameters) states:

> Specify request parameters as key-value pairs (string-to-string mappings), with a destination as the key and a source as the value.
>
> Specify the destination by using the following pattern integration.request.location.name, where location is querystring, path, or header, and name is a valid, unique parameter name.
>
> The source must be an existing method request parameter or a static value. You must enclose static values in single quotation marks and pre-encode these values based on their destination in the request.

My code looks compliant with what stated since I used 'integration.request.querystring.customvalue' as destination/key and a static value enclosed in single quotes as source/value.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The source must be an existing method request parameter or a static value. You must enclose static values in single quotation marks and pre-encode these values based on their destination in the request.

It means that the value itself as it gets published to CloudFormation stack and later to API Gateway should be enclosed in single quotation marks.

The quotation marks in `'123456789'` are a part of the JavaScript code. The value defined with this code is the string `123456789`, without the quotation marks.

Try this:

```
requestParameters: {
   'integration.request.querystring.customvalue': "'123456789'"
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that made the template deploy correctly, but I'm thinking that is not what i needed. I mean, running a test on the api gateway endpoint I can see from the test logs/output that `customvalue` is being correclty appended to the called url in the query string with the correct value, but checking the lambda function logs in Cloudwatch (i logged the entire `event` parameter) i cannot see `customvalue`. Maybe I need another solution?

Comment: @fudo: maybe you do, and that would make a good new question. Ask it!